# How to get rid of the warning when forcing cast of protected Object in super class?

Tags: java

I have a base class like this:

```
class Base {
    protected Object a;

    Base(Object a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

and then, a daugher class:

```
class Daugher extends Base {
    /*
    ... some attributes ....
    */     

    Daughter(Pair<L, R> a) {
        super(a);

    /*
    .... some methods ....
    */

    public void mathodX() {

        ....
        ((Pair <L, R>) a).getLeft().SomeSpecificMethodOfObjectTypeL()
        ....
    }

}
```

Note: Pair is specifically the org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair object, but I suppose the same would apply for other structures like Map, List etc...

So, if I want to use specific methods from the forced Object type, I'm forced to do the ugly casting as above.
However, this cast raises "unchecked cast" warning in Eclipse, so it's not so good.
If I try to insert a check (e.g. " if (a instanceof Pair) " etc ... ) I'm told that I cannot use instanceof check with a specific assignment but I should check it with Pair. But this wouldn't be pointless, given that then I want to reach methods specific to L (or R) ?

Putting the question in a broader sense, what is the most correct way to manipulate protected generic objects in the super class?

I apologize if the problem is not stated in the best way, I'm not a Java professional.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You actually can't know for sure that `a` is a `Pair<L,R>`. Since it's not final, it could have been changed for all you know, and the compiler is correct to warn you about it.

Comment: Yes I understand your point and I understood why the compiler raises the warning -- I just wonder what is the most correct way to check that Object a is an instance of Pair<L,R>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to go would be to use generics:

```
class Base<T> {
    protected T a;

    Base(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class Daugher<L, R> extends Base<Pair<L, R>> {
    Daugher (Pair<L, R> a) {
        super (a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

to your method or suppress this type of warnings

Comment: This is in fact what Eclipse suggests to do, but looks like a masking of bad programming behaviour to me :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the above or you can declare methodx differently.

```
public <L,R> void methodX{

}
```

The compiler enforces the type then.

check out [generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Comment: Tnx, will check it out !